# Get contents of a zip file

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, fetch, jszip

This `URL` below points to a zip file which contains a file called `bundlesizes.json`. I am trying to read the contents of that `json` file within my `React` application (no `node` server/backend involved)

```
https://dev.azure.com/uifabric/cd9e4e13-b8db-429a-9c21-499bf1c98639/_apis/build/builds/8838/artifacts?artifactName=drop&api-version=4.1&%24format=zip
```

I was able to get the contents of the `zip` file by doing the following

```
const url =
  'https://dev.azure.com/uifabric/cd9e4e13-b8db-429a-9c21-499bf1c98639/_apis/build/builds/8838/artifacts?artifactName=drop&api-version=4.1&%24format=zip';
const response = await Axios({
  url,
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'stream'
});
console.log(response.data);
```

This emits the zip file (`non-ascii` characters). However, I am looking to read the contents of the `bundlesizes.json` file within it.

For that I looked up `jszip` and tried the following,

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.createReader(
  new zip.BlobReader(response.data),
  function(reader: any) {
    // get all entries from the zip
    reader.getEntries(function(entries: any) {
      if (entries.length) {
        // get first entry content as text
        entries[0].getData(
          new zip.TextWriter(),
          function(text: any) {
            // text contains the entry data as a String
            console.log(text);

            // close the zip reader
            reader.close(function() {
              // onclose callback
            });
          },
          function(current: any, total: any) {
            // onprogress callback
            console.log(current);
            console.log(total);
          }
        );
      }
    });
  },
  function(error: any) {
    // onerror callback
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

However, this does not work for me, and errors out.
This is the error I receive

[image]

How can I read the contents of the file within the zip within my `React` application by using `Javascript`/`Typescript`?